# How to Display BigQuery dataset on Firebase Analytics dashboard or event's board

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, looker-studio

The scenario here is that I have my Firebase Analytics project linked to BigQuery and created queries/dataset. I then connected the BigQuery with Data Studio to create visual reports for the datasets. Every thing is fine up to this point, my problem is:

- how to display the Data Studio reports on my Firebase Analytics dashboard or Event's board?
- If the above is not possible, how can I export BigQuery data source back to Firebase Analytics?

All what I want is to achieve something like Firebase Analytics User_Engagement report for the Screen_View event, like below image

[image]

Thankyou in advance, any help will be highly appreciated.

Dawit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do either of these things.

Analytics data is exported to BigQuery but external data cannot be imported or displayed on the dashboard.

I would create the visual reports in DataStudio and share those instead of using the dashboard.

Comment: We just decided to design a full dashboard in Data Studio and ignore Firebase Analytics, as it is useless in our case. Now we are only using Firebase Analytics to collect data related to our custom events